# Can't read response data and headers in an AngularJS interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I have an API in my server that sends a custom header (lets name it "customHeader") that responds to `http://localhost:8081/my/test/api`.

I'm trying to read that custom response header from an interceptor in angularJS:

```
angular.module('oauth.interceptor', []).factory('readResponseHeader', ['$q',
        function ($q) {
            return {
                response': function(response) {
                    console.log("response: %o", JSON.stringify(response));
                    console.log("headers: %o", response.headers());
                    return response;
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

But all I get are empty data and headers in response. The console log shows the following json as *response*:

```
{
  "data": [],
  "status": 200,
  "config": {
    "method": "POST",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "url": "http://localhost:8081/my/test/api",
    "data": {
      "example": "request data"
    },
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      "Authorization": "Bearer XXXXXXXXX..."
    },
    "cached": false
  },
  "statusText": "OK"
}
```

And the following as *headers*:

```
{
  "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
}
```

I expected my `customHeader` to be there, and be able to read it with something like:

```
response.headers().customHeader
```

But it clearly isn't there (in fact, many other headers are missing!).
How am I supposed to read it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem wasn't really in the AngularJS part, but on the server side part.

The point is that, to be able to access the header, the server must add the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header containing the name of the custom header, something like this:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: customHeader
```